# Accessing Parent of Inline Form Sets in template?

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I am wondering how to access the parent of the inline form set in Django. Here is what I am currently doing:

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    [Code Ommitted]
    formSet = inlineformset_factory(Tombstone, Tank, form = TombstoneForm)
        form = formSet(instance=t)
        return render(request, 'edit_form2.html', {'form': form})
```

In this instance I want to access the Tombstone object in my template.

Edit: I want to access the form element associated with each field in the Tombstone object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use formset's `instance` attribute:

```
{{ form.instance.id }}
```

Comment: Okay awesome, that give the value! Is there a way to generate the designated form element? i.e. a textbox for a textfield?

Comment: @JordanRose you need to allow user edit parent element also? In this case you can use additional modelform for your instance. Something like this: http://bitofpixels.com/blog/form-and-formset-in-one-html-form/ but you need pass instance argument to the form and formset.

Comment: Yeah this is what I need I believe.